# Specifying task path in Task Scheduler for changing it with schtasks

Tags: windows, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to enable/disable a task, but /tn results in "does not exist in the system" because it's not in Task Scheduler's root library but in one of its subfolders. I tried it with /tn "\folder1\folder2\taskname" but I still get "does not exist".

Note: I am not talking about the path for the task to run at, but about the path of the task itself inside Task Scheduler's folder tree.